# Installing and importing OPENCV ubuntu

Tags: python, opencv

Im trying different methods but still could not make opencv work on my Ubuntu.

Every time I try to import `cv2` I receive:

```
ImportError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-72fbbcfe2587> in <module>()
----> 1 import cv2

ImportError: No module named cv2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing opencv](http://askubuntu.com/questions/334158/installing-opencv)

Answer (score 0):

What methods did you try? Can you try this instruction http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/